# How to extract only URLs that contains subdomains

Tags: regex, linux, search, grep

My original file contains:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
google.com
facebook.com
yahoo.com
tt.twitter.com
yy.notexist
```

I want to extract the lines which contains sub domains. Which are:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
```

I tried this regex:

```
grep -P '^.[^.]+\.(.[^.])+\..[^.]+$' test.csv
```

But it gives only:

```
mail.google.com
```

I could not figure out why it does not see the rest. I am not sure if my regex is perfect and capture all cases. I am not sure how to express (any character except dot) which I use `^.[^.]` to express it in regex. Can you correct me please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could achieve the requirement posted by my question by the following command:

```
grep -P '^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.)+[^.]+'
```

It is simple command to identify those URLs with more than one dot which means they have sub-domains. However, this will not distinguish whether uni.ac.uk is main or sub domain. Ideally, another stage of processing using one of the libraries that have more advaced techniques to identify the main domains from those URLs with more than one dot. One example of those libraries is [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract).

Answer (score 3):

Answer based on given sample input/output, doesn't have intelligence to distinguish what is a top-level domain or not

```
$ awk -F. 'NF>2 || $NF!="com"' ip.txt
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
yy.notexist

$ # any domain, not just .com
$ awk -F. 'NF>2' ip.txt
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
```

- `-F.` set `.` as input field separator

  - some versions may require `-F'[.]'` instead of `-F.`
- `NF>2 || $NF!="com"` print line if it has more than 2 fields or if last field is not `com`

With `grep`

```
$ grep -xv '[^.]*\.com' ip.txt
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
yy.notexist

$ # any domain, not just .com
$ grep -xv '[^.]*\.[^.]*' ip.txt
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
```

- `-x` match only whole line
- `-v` to print lines not matching the given regex
- `[^.]*` non `.` characters
- `\.com` to match `.com`

Comment: The grep pattern will prints any text lines such as `random text`

Comment: true, as mentioned this is based on given sample and doesn't have any intelligence built in...

Comment: Actually `awk -F'[.]' 'NF>2' ip.txt` works, however `awk -F'[.]' 'NF>2 || $NF!="com"' ip.txt` prints everything

Comment: in that case, you probably have dos style line ending, check with `cat -v grepdomain.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following expression:

[^(?:(?:[a-z0-9]+.){2,}com|[a-z0-9]+(?!.com).[a-z]+)$](https://regex101.com/r/8ittZs/5)

**Regex breakdown:**

- `^` Beginning of string.
- `(?:` Non capturing group.

  - `(?:[a-z0-9]+\.){2,}com` Non capturing group, which matches lower case letters or numbers, followed by a full stop. The pattern is repeated more 2 or more times. Matches `com` afterwards.
  - `|` Alternation, OR.
  - `[a-z0-9]+(?!\.com)\.[a-z]+` Lower case letters or numbers, not followed by `.com`, followed by `.` and alphabetic characters.
- `)` Close non capturing group.
- `$` End of string.

---

The command:

```
grep -P '^(?:(?:[a-z0-9]+\.){2,}com|[a-z0-9]+(?!\.com)\.[a-z]+)$' test.csv
```

Prints:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
yy.notexist
```

---

**EDIT:**

As per your edit, use:

[^(?:[a-z0-9]+.){2,}com$](https://regex101.com/r/8ittZs/7).

Command:

```
grep -P '^(?:[a-z0-9]+\.){2,}com$' test.csv
```

Prints:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
```

Comment: The presupposition that the number of labels reveals whether something is a subdomain is a radical oversimplification. In their respective hierarchies, `arizona.edu`, `google.co.in` and `greatneck.k12.ny.us` are top-level domains.

Comment: Perhaps OP did not choose the right words then. My answer solves OP's problems from the information he shared.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I find your answer too complicated. My requirement is that I am just looking for lines that appears to have subdomains. If it is `example.com` this does not contain sub domains. If it is like: `(sub.)+example.com` then it contains subdomains where (sub)+ can be repeated one or more times. I will do another stage to figure our the main domain using some python libraries. My question is just to extract those lines with the format `(sub)+.example.com`.

Comment: *I find your answer too complicated* It works, I don't understand your point.

Comment: I am sure you can do this other ways, but using repeated non capturing groups is more concise. Your regex is wrong and I gave you a working solution. The way I see it, it has to be done this way, otherwise you will never be able to deal with a variable number of subdomains.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this solution seems to do the purpose in much simpler way: `grep -P '^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.)+[^.]+'` I will post it if nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It does not match `yy.notexist`.

Comment: @ UnbearableLightness Sorry about that, that entry was a typo. It should not be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You get only 1 match because you regex would match 3 parts separated by 2 dots so that would not match:

```
srv1.mail.google.com
google.com
facebook.com
yahoo.com
```

You don't match `tt.twitter.com` because of this part `(.[^.])+\.` which would capture a group that repeats one or more times matching a single character followed by not a dot which will match 2 characters per repetition followed by a literal dot.

This would for example not match `twitter.` because that contains 7 characters and a dot and the repetition is per 2 so `twitte.` would match.

It looks like you want to match not a dot separated by at least 2 dots. If you want to keep the pattern `[^.]+` to not match a dot, you might use:

`grep -P '^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){2,}$' test.csv`

This will match:

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `[^.]+` match not a dot one or more times
- `(?:\.[^.]+){2,}` Non capturing group that repeats at least 2 times that matches a literal dot followed by not a dot one or more times
- `$` Assert end of the string